# How to build a popup workflow in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

Please refer the flow below:
[image: Desired workflow]

What I would like is for the first screen to launch a screen where View A is shown and a button that can close the screen. Clicking on "X" gets the view back to the main screen. On clicking on a button in View A, View B should be shown. But, View B should be shown within the same region as View   A, so that the lower view with the "X" button is visible. View B can then probably segue to other view controllers. But anytime the "X" button is pressed, we should go back to the screen that launched view A (the main controller in this case).

I got the first three screens working. But when I segue from View A to View B, it covers the entire screen. Any ideas on how I can just replace View A with View B. When View B is shown, I also want to be able to add a Back button to go back to View A.

This is very similar to how Quora iOS app shows specific answers.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: Why you don't use Navigation Controller?

Comment: Navigation controller will replace entire View. I want to just replace the top container view with View B. I want the lower view to remain and be able to close at any point.